# What is the use of boost::asio::async_write function

Tags: sockets, boost, boost-asio

Can anyone please help me with this code , what is the use of "boost::asio::async_write" function here

Does it sends acknowledgment back to the client ?

```
 void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
          size_t bytes_transferred)
      {
        if (!error)
        {
          boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
              boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
              boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
          delete this;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is from an "echo server" example. `async_write` writes the contents of `boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred)` to the socket.

Since we're inside `handle_read` we can guess that this function itself is the completion handler for a likely `async_read` call that filled that `data_` buffer. Since we use the exact number of bytes reported back by `async_read` (`bytes_transferred`) and there's no visible manipulation on `data_`, we can assume that this simply sends the exact message (or data in general) received to `socket_`. If `socket_` was also the endpoint in the `async_read` this is the definition of an [echo server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol).